# Why does the OS freeze?

Tags: kernel, 22.04, dell

My Dell laptop 7390 sometimes freezes. The computer does not react to the keyboard and does not answer ping (or ssh, which is enabled). The last entries before I force a reboot with the on/off switch shows the following. Where should I look for a solution to this?

```
Nov  6 09:18:04 dellux kernel: [ 2503.034726] audit: type=1400 audit(1699258684.557:892): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" 
name="/etc/igfx_user_feature.txt" pid=3053 comm="FSBroker4967" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Nov  6 09:18:04 dellux kernel: [ 2503.034808] audit: type=1400 audit(1699258684.557:893): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" 
name="/etc/igfx_user_feature_next.txt" pid=3053 comm="FSBroker4967" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Nov  6 09:18:15 dellux kernel: [ 2513.887305] audit: type=1400 audit(1699258695.413:894): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" 
name="/etc/igfx_user_feature_next.txt" pid=3053 comm="FSBroker4967" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Nov  6 09:18:15 dellux kernel: [ 2513.887661] audit: type=1400 audit(1699258695.413:895): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" 
name="/etc/igfx_user_feature.txt" pid=3053 comm="FSBroker4967" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Nov  6 09:18:20 dellux kernel: [ 2518.923040] audit: type=1400 audit(1699258700.449:896): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" 
name="/etc/igfx_user_feature.txt" pid=3053 comm="FSBroker4967" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Nov  6 09:18:20 dellux kernel: [ 2518.923273] audit: type=1400 audit(1699258700.449:897): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" 
name="/etc/igfx_user_feature_next.txt" pid=3053 comm="FSBroker4967" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Nov  6 09:18:20 dellux kernel: [ 2518.926283] audit: type=1400 audit(1699258700.449:898): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/etc/igfx_user_feature_next.txt" pid=3053 comm="FSBroker4967" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Nov  6 09:18:20 dellux kernel: [ 2518.926537] audit: type=1400 audit(1699258700.449:899): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/etc/igfx_user_feature.txt" pid=3053 comm="FSBroker4967" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

Answer (score -1):

System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab fallocate` to create some. Swap space must be contiguous. use `mkswap` or `fallocate`, not `dd`. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

Comment: No, large programs or running out of memory does not seem to be the problem. free reports typically 75% free memory and nearly 100% free swap.

Comment: Read your log file. The last two lines complain that  `snap.firefox.firefox` is not xa

Comment: Read your log file. The last two lines complain that  `snap.firefox.firefox` is not allowed to access two files (the `name=` filenames). There's a known problem. with snaps accessing files outside the snap.  Try: uninstall the `firefox`snap (`man snap`) and install the `dpkg` version. `man apt-cache apt-get apt`.